# Cypher LOAD CSV - how to create a linked list of nodes ordered by a property?

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

Im new to Neo4j and looking for some guidance :-)

Basically I want to create the graph below from the csv below. The NEXT relationship is created between Points based on the order of their property *sequence*. I would like to be able to ignore if *sequence*s are consecutive. Any ideas?

(s1:Shape)-[:POINTS]->(p1:Point)

(s1:Shape)-[:POINTS]->(p2:Point)

(s1:Shape)-[:POINTS]->(p3:Point)

(p1)-[:NEXT]->(p2)

(p2)[:NEXT]->(p3)

and so on

```
shape_id,shape_pt_lat,shape_pt_lon,shape_pt_sequence,shape_dist_traveled
"1-700-y11-1.1.I","53.42646060879","-6.23930113514121","1","0"
"1-700-y11-1.1.I","53.4268571616632","-6.24059395687542","2","96.6074531286277"
"1-700-y11-1.1.I","53.4269700485041","-6.24093540883784","3","122.549696670773"
"1-700-y11-1.1.I","53.4270439028769","-6.24106779537932","4","134.591291249566"
"1-700-y11-1.1.I","53.4268623569266","-6.24155684094256","5","172.866609667575"
"1-700-y11-1.1.I","53.4268380666968","-6.2417384245122","6","185.235926544428"
"1-700-y11-1.1.I","53.4268874080753","-6.24203735638874","7","205.851454672516"
"1-700-y11-1.1.I","53.427394066848","-6.24287421729846","8","285.060040065768"
"1-700-y11-1.1.I","53.4275257974236","-6.24327509689195","9","315.473852717259"
"1-700-y11-1.2.O","53.277024711771","-6.20739084216546","1","0"
"1-700-y11-1.2.O","53.2777605784999","-6.20671521402849","2","93.4772699644143"
"1-700-y11-1.2.O","53.2780318605927","-6.2068238246152","3","124.525619356934"
"1-700-y11-1.2.O","53.2786209984572","-6.20894363498438","4","280.387737910482"
"1-700-y11-1.2.O","53.2791038678913","-6.21057305710353","5","401.635418300665"
"1-700-y11-1.2.O","53.2790975844245","-6.21075327761739","6","413.677012879457"
"1-700-y11-1.2.O","53.2792296384738","-6.21116766400758","7","444.981964564454"
"1-700-y11-1.2.O","53.2799500357098","-6.21065767664905","8","532.073870043666"
"1-700-y11-1.2.O","53.2800290799386","-6.2105343995296","9","544.115464622458"
"1-700-y11-1.2.O","53.2815594673093","-6.20949562301196","10","727.987702875002"
```

It is the 3rd part that I cant finish. Creating the NEXT relationship!

```
//1. Create Shape
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///D:\\shapes.txt' AS csv
With distinct csv.shape_id as ids
Foreach (x in ids | merge (s:Shape {id: x} ));

//2. Create Point, and Shape to Point relationship
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///D:\\shapes.txt' AS csv
MATCH (s:Shape {id: csv.shape_id})
with s, csv
MERGE (s)-[:POINTS]->(p:Point {id: csv.shape_id, 
lat : csv.shape_pt_lat, lon : csv.shape_pt_lat, 
sequence : toInt(csv.shape_pt_sequence), dist_travelled : csv.shape_dist_traveled});

//3.Create Point to Point relationship
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///D:\\shapes.txt' AS csv
???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) installed for this one. It has both a means of batch processing, and a quick way to link all nodes in a collection together.

Since you already have all shapes the the points of the shape in the db, you don't need to do another load csv, just use the data you've got.

We'll use [apoc.periodic.iterate()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_iterate) to batch process each shape, and [apoc.nodes.link()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) to link all ordered points in the shape by relationships.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (s:Shape) RETURN s",
  "WITH {s} as shape 
   MATCH (shape)-[:POINTS]->(point:Point)
   WITH shape, point
   ORDER by point.sequence ASC
   WITH shape, COLLECT(point) as points
   CALL apoc.nodes.link(points,'NEXT')", 
  {batchSize:1000, parallel:true}) YIELD batches, total
  RETURN batches, total
```

EDIT

Looks like there may be a bug when using procedure calls within the apoc.periodic.iterate() where no mutating operations occur (attempted this after including a SET operation in the second part of the query to set a property on some nodes, the property was not added).

Unsure if this is a general case of procedure calls being executed within procedure calls, or if this is specific to apoc.periodic.iterate(), or if this only occurs with both iterate() and link().

I'll file a bug if I can learn more about the cause. In the meantime, if you don't need batching, you can forgo apoc.periodic.iterate():

```
   MATCH (shape:Shape)-[:POINTS]->(point:Point)
   WITH shape, point
   ORDER by point.sequence ASC
   WITH shape, COLLECT(point) as points
   CALL apoc.nodes.link(points,'NEXT')
```

Comment: For whatever reason, the relationships are not created. It correctly returns that the correct number of batches. apoc.perioidic.iterate does commit changes I assume! Maybe you cant call another procedure within apoc.perioidic.iterate?   I did get this to execute successfully, but it isnt batched:  MATCH (s:Shape)  
WITH s  
MATCH (s)-[:POINTS]->(point:Point) 
WITH s, point 
ORDER by point.sequence ASC  
WITH s, COLLECT(point) as points  
CALL apoc.nodes.link(points,'NEXT')  
return s;

Comment: Interesting find, I was able to replicate this too. Altered my answer to note the bug and suggest the simplified query without the batching that worked for you.